# Gauge symmetry and the volume in phase space

Tags: gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, volume

Recently, I am reading a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.05289) about the soft theorem and large gauge symmetry which is non-zero in the boundary.

In section 6, the author introduces the covariant phase space method to illuminate why the large gauge symmetry is non-trivial, and the key argument locates at P40-P41.

Roughly, there is the statement that if the corresponding symplectic form $\Omega$ which is interpreted as the volume of phase space in this literature is non-zero, this field transformation is non-trivial. Or, say,  if this transformation is not tangent to **gauge orbit**, it is meaningful.

**My main questions are**

- Are there some more physically strict arguments about this viewpoint? These papers or books should discuss gauge symmetry in the language of covariant phase space. Especially, it should explain what is the non-trivial gauge symmetry.
- The definition of $\Omega$ depends on the choice of Cauchy slice. Does the significance of field transformation depend on the choice?
- Following this paper, any gauge transformation with the non-vanishing value and derivative in boundary in some orders inevitably leads to a non-zero volume. Are these transformations all meaningful?

---

**Update**

For question 2, I have an unsatisfactory answer for myself. The pre-symplectic current is weakly(if and only if on-shell) closed, and thus the definition of $\Omega$ is weakly independent with the choice of Cauchy slice. But to the quantum level (allows off-shell), dose the uniqueness still hold?

Comment: 1) Not sure what exactly you're looking for. 2) Definition of $\Omega$ does not depend on the choice of Cauchy slice. 3) Yes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 1) I am looking for papers or books discussing gauge symmetry in the language of covariant phase space. Especially, it should explain what is the non-trivial gauge symmetry.

Comment: Most references in this context deal with diffeomorphism symmetry. https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616 is a good reference for this. If you are specifically looking for something on gauge theories, then https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.14334 might be helpful (Disclaimer: this is my work).

Comment: Comment on the update: $\Omega$ is does not depend on the Cauchy slice at all. At best, it can depend on the boundary of a Cauchy slice but even this is fixed by imposing appropriate boundary conditions on the fields. For instance, the matching conditions is one such boundary condition that ensures that the symplectic form does not depend on the Cauchy slice.